# C# SqlParameters are not being passed into query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

#### Sql Command construction

I've built the Sql command as follows:

```
    string _InsertVehicleQuery = "INSERT INTO VSI_VehicleRecords(StockNumber,Status,Make,Model,Colour,Spefication) VALUES (@StockNumber, @Status, '@Make', '@Model', '@Colour', '@Specification');";

    SqlCommand _InsertVehicleCommand = new SqlCommand(_InsertVehicleQuery);
    _InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StockNumber", __StockNumber));
    _InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", __Status));
    _InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Make", Make));
    _InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Model", Model));
    _InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Colour", Colour));
    _InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Specification", Specification));
```

#### Sql Command execution

```
    //Method call
    DataUtility.NonQuery(_InsertVehicleCommand);

    //Method structure
    public static void NonQuery(SqlCommand Command)
    {
        Command.Connection = __Connection;

        OpenConnection();
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        CloseConnection();
    }
```

Is there anything blindingly obvious that i'm not doing within the execution or construction of the SQL Query. The result that I get in the database table:

```
VehicleRecordID StockNumber Status  Make    Model   Colour  Spefication
1                 -1            0   @Make   @Model  @Colour @Specification
```

Thanks in advance for any solution, also any suggestions are also welcomed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter names should not be in single quotes in the `VALUES` list as they will be interpreted as string literals.

Comment: Oh yeah! Can't believe that I didn't catch on that only the parameters with the single quotes didn't pull through.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put the quotes around the parameters
ie

```
... (@StockNumber, @Status, @Make, @Model, @Colour, @Specification);";
```

instead of

```
... (@StockNumber, @Status, '@Make', '@Model', '@Colour', '@Specification');";
```

Also, you can use AddWithValue

```
_InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Make", Make);
```

instead of

```
_InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Make", Make));
```

Answer (score 1):

don't put  '@parameter'  around your parameters

```
string _InsertVehicleQuery = "INSERT INTO VSI_VehicleRecords(StockNumber,Status,Make,Model,Colour,Spefication) VALUES (@StockNumber, @Status, @Make, @Model, @Colour, @Specification);";

    SqlCommand _InsertVehicleCommand = new SqlCommand(_InsertVehicleQuery);
    _InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StockNumber", __StockNumber));
    _InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", __Status));
    _InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Make", Make));
    _InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Model", Model));
    _InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Colour", Colour));
    _InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Specification", Specification));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove from parameters definition the `@` character and also quotes `'`.

Then set the Value property of each parameter addes

new SqlParameter("StockNumber", __StockNumber).Value = value;